# How to check if a string ends with another string in C

Tags: c, string, string.h

I take image name from the `argv[]` and I need to check if the format is `".jpg"` or `".jpeg"` or `".ppm"`, but since there is no `substring()` in `string.h`, I'm forced to do it like this:

```
if (imIn[strlen(imgIn) - 4] == '.'
&& imgIn[strlen(imgIn) - 3] == 'j'
&& imgIn[strlen(imgIn) - 2] == 'p'
&& imgIn[strlen(imgIn) - 1] == 'g') {..}
```

But that takes too much space and I was wondering if I could do something like this

```
if (strstr(substring(imgIn, strlen(imgIn) - 4, 4), ".jpg") == NULL) {...}.
```

The problem why I don't just use just `strstr()` alone is that it would approve something like `"jpg.png"` since it checks the entire strings for the occurance.

Comment: You could pass `imgIn + strlen(imgIn) - 4` to `strcmp` as parameter

Comment: After checking if the length is larger than 4, `const char * ext = imgIn + strlen(imIn) - 4` will give you the pointer to the first char of the extension. After that it's a matter of calling `strcmp(ext, ".jpg")`. Alternatively, check if `strstr` returns `imIn + strlen(imIn) - 4`.

Comment: For file extensions in particular, I often use [strrchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strrchr/): `const char *ext = strrchr( imgIn, '.' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `strcmp` takes an address of a `const char *`, then we can pass the address of the character at position `strlen(imgIn) - 3`

```
const char *img       = "some_picture.jpg";
const char *extension = img + strlen(img) - 3;

if(!strcmp(extension, "jpg"))
        printf("%s", "JPG extension");
```

However, there is a problem. What if the extension is `jpeg`, then `extension` would contain `peg`. In this case, one solution would be to iterate through the string backward until we hit the first `.` character.

```
const char *get_extension(const char *img, size_t sz) {

    const char *ptr;

    ptr = img;
    img += sz;

    for(; img != ptr; --img) {

        if(*img == '.')
            return(img + 1);
    }

    return(NULL);

}


const char *img       = "some_picture.jpeg";
const char *extension = get_extension(img, strlen(img));

if(extension != NULL)
    /* handle valid input */
else 
    /* handle invalid input */
```

Comment: Nice but I would be careful with checking only `"jpg"`. We need to see that there even is an extension. It might approve `"picturejpg`" for example. I would rather check for `".jpg"`.

Comment: @tomashauser I have edited the code. It returns ```NULL``` if the input contains no extension.

Comment: See [`strrchr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) to reverse search a character.